# angular component html is escaping my superscript character

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some text, in an angular 5 component as follows.

**Area Breakdown m²**

Unfortunately angular is breaking my neat little squared character and displaying this:

**Area Breakdown m&sup2;**

`component.ts`

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: `component.html`
})
export class SourceDocumentWorkItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    // (all very standard)
}
```

`component.html`

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="bold">Area Breakdown m&sup2;</label>
</div>
```

How do I stop angular from mangling my html... I am pretty sure angular is the culprit here.

Comment: can you please provide a plunker

Comment: Not sure why, tested on stackblitz same issue, alternatively you can use `Area Breakdown m&#0178;` or `<sup>2</sup>` (this is a bit larger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `[innerHTML]` instead as below it gives the output as per your requirement:

```
areaBreakdownText:string='Area Breakdown m&sup2;';
<label class="bold" [innerHTML]="areaBreakdownText"></label>
```

Comment: used this, literal string also works: `<label [innerHtml]="'Area Breakdown m&sup2;'"></label>`