# UTF-8 symbol not working in angular2

Tags: angular, utf-8

In angular2 app, I am trying to use UTF-8 symbol but it is not showing properly, 
Do I need to add some extra package/code for using same?

in .ts file, i'm using

```
title = '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81';
```

and in HTML file i am rendring this as

```
{{title}}
```

PS: Actually I have to use this utf-8 encode string in Primeng chart as a label, instead of number or normal string. I am not able to set any HTML element there like image etc. so thinking about setting utf-8 code to set images as string.

Comment: Can you add a snippet to show how you're using UTF-8 symbols?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya please see my updated question.

Comment: You can use it like, <div [innerHTML]="title"></div>

Comment: already tried but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular component html is escaping my superscript character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800533/angular-component-html-is-escaping-my-superscript-character)

Answer (score 2):

In the component class:

```
symbol = '&#x1F601;';
```

In the HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="symbol"></div>
```

Instead of bytes use Unicode.

Unicode `U+1F601` should be written as `&#x1F601;`

Check the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnqenw)

Comment: as I already said , i have tried this already but not working.

Comment: What is the symbol that you want to show in the HTML?

Comment: I am trying any random symbol from here  https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: Thanks, working. But in my use case, i can't use `innerHTML` I need to set in .ts file only as I explained in my question I am working on Charts. so there we only need to set string or number not anything like HTML element like image etc.